# ScaleTo and TranslateTo not working everywhere?

Tags: xamarin

I've got a Xamarin app that uses ScaleTo And TranslateTo in a number of places, and I just noticed that's it's not working anymore. I've got it wrapped up in a BeginInvokeOnMainThread like usual. But here's the thing... it works fine on an iPad Pro. And an iPhone xS. As well as an android API 23 phone. But I've also got an android 23 tablet here, and on that device ScaleTo and TranslateTo finish instantly. No smooth transition. Same thing with an android 28 emulator. If I put a Stopwatch on there, I can clearly see that the devices it works on are taking 1000ms like they should. But on the other 2 devices it's finishing in 5ms. Are these routines device specific perhaps? The other thing is I could swear this was working fine last week on all devices. I did update my xamarin forms to the latest version Monday. Maybe something got broke? Or maybe it never worked on these few devices and I just never noticed. Anyone have an idea?

```
    private bool Test()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await winMessage.ScaleTo(2, 1000, Easing.SpringOut);
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the latest Xam.Forms. Did you update anything else on Monday? It may be worth trying to revert back the Xam.Forms version to confirm this is a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see some threads in Github issues of Xamarin.forms says:

[Animations are not working in 4.2.0.709249](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7291)

[fix animations not animating](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7298)

And it looks like fixed now, please updated to the version `4.2.0.778463` to check if your problem still exist.

If the problem still happens, you can open a new issue and add your description there.

You can also downgrade to 4.1 to make your codes work.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Just broken. Updated to latest Xamarin today and now everything is well across all devices.